# Get files from cherry pick to a certain commit

Tags: git

If I cherry pick a commit and after that I run

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

command and have all files in stageing area.
If I run `git reset HEAD` I'll get the file in working directory.
How can I completely got rid of a file from tracking and get it up to date ?

Comment: Do you want to get rid of it *from the repo altogether*? or just from the commit you're preparing?

Comment: just from the commit, to have it like in latest commit.

Comment: OK, thought so. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `git checkout -- <filepath>` to reset all changes in said file, and restore it as it is on `HEAD` (last commit on current branch)

Comment: greaat, Thank a lot! can I do it with 1 command instead of 2 ?

Comment: You could do `git reset HEAD~1` as your first command, to avoid having to do `git reset HEAD` to unstage, but you'll have to restore the file(s) to exclude afterwards as a separate command. If there are multiple files to restore, just list them all after the `--`

Comment: You could do `git reset --hard HEAD~1` to reset HEAD and remove all file changes from the new cherry-picked commit.  Your workspace and staging area will represent the new HEAD exactly.  Note that `--hard` removes all local changes so don't use it if you have local changes you want to keep.

Comment: @Cameron121341 To shorten the overall process, you can also do `git cherry-pick -n <yourCommit>` then `git checkout -- <file1> [<file2> ...]`